# collect result from alert dialog and continue execution of code once result received

Tags: android, dialog, alert, collect

My code should show an alert dialog with list of strings. once user selects one, that string I need to use.

I have function handleIt() in main activity which calls getTagSelectionFromDialogBox(). There is public String selectedTitle and public integer title_position.

I am seeing an issue that from handleIt() I am calling getTagSelectionFromDialogBox() after that I am calling a Toast to print selectedTitle.

I am seeing issue here that both alert dialog and Toast are getting executed and Toast shows null (since it is initialized as null) instead it Toast waiting for getTagSelectionFromDialogBox() complete. Here is my code

I need some mechanism to wait till alert get the result and (which is a string here) and I need to do lot of work with that string which I want to do it after getTagSelectionFromDialogBox() and i do not want to do it in onClick() of DialogInterface.OnClickListener().

Below is code snip
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity NavigationDrawerFragment.FragmentDrawerListener{

```
public String selectedTitle = null;
public int title_position;
public  String[] navTitles = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // do some work 
    navTitiles = getnavTitles() // fills lsit
    handlit();
    }

void handleRest(Intent intent) {
        getTagSelectionFromDialogBox();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"category selected: "+ selectedTitle, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

public void getTagSelectionFromDialogBox() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Select tag");
        alertDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(navTitles, -1, new             DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    title_position = which;
                selectedTitle = navTitles[which];
                dialog.cancel();
                    }
        });

    AlertDialog ad = alertDialog.create();
    ad.show();
}
```

}

After toast I have to use selectedTitile and do some database operations which I do not want to do in onClick()

how can I achieve this??

Answer (score 0):

instead of putting it right after the call to your function which shows the dialog box, you could put the toast in an other function which is called when you click on the button like this :

```
public String selectedTitle = null;
public int title_position;
public  String[] navTitles = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // do some work 
    navTitiles = getnavTitles() // fills lsit
    handlit();
}

void handleRest(Intent intent) {
    getTagSelectionFromDialogBox();
}

private void showToast() {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"category selected: "+ selectedTitle, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void getTagSelectionFromDialogBox() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new     AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Select tag");
    alertDialog.setSingleChoiceItems(navTitles, -1, new             DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                title_position = which;
            selectedTitle = navTitles[which];
            showToast();
            dialog.cancel();
                }
    });

    AlertDialog ad = alertDialog.create();
    ad.show();
}
```

Hope it helps

EDIT : According to your comment : replace the following line

```
showToast();
```

by

```
showToast(selectedTitle);
```

and then you just have to get the input in the other function like this :

```
private void showToast(String selectedTitle) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"category selected: "+ selectedTitle, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: As of now i am just using selectedTitle in Toast just to print the input. But what i require I need to use that string once i get it from the alert box.

with above code Toast aftergetTagSelectionFromDialogBox() is executed before or along with the alert dialog. what I want is code next to getTagSelectionFromDialogBox() should execute with the result received after getTagSelectionFromDialogBox() call.

Comment: Response edited, you just have to pass the title as an argument